# Google Data Studio MySql data source connection does not exist Error

Tags: looker-studio

Platform: Google Data Studio

Data Source: MySQL

Connection was working before, 
meaning no issues with credentials.

All of a sudden, getting the below error:

[image]

All IPs have been whitelisted from the google data studio list of ips.

The only thing that comes to mind is a limitation of GDS to process data.
The data source table has around 200K+ rows.

Not sure what is the limitation for GDS with MySQL. 
There's no indication anywhere.

Anyone out there can help to solve this or maybe provide some info would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I had a similar error when I was using the IP address of the SQL instance instead of the SQL name. Would help to check that?

Comment: About the limit, it's 100K rows https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031

Answer (score 1):

If you use a firewall, be sure to double check the Google ip adresses. They may have added new ips (in my case, the last one was missing).

[Check them here !](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031#notes)

After doing so, I had to change the Host name of the connection to the database for a url alias (`www.yourserver.com` <- url pointing on your server), and change it back to the IP to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a the connector cannot establish a new connection.

**Cloud SQL Connector:**
 At the time of writing this, the connector seems unable to establish a new connection once the existing one has timed out and modifying the JDBC url to include query parameters gives you an error when authenticating. 
This is probably due to the connector appending it's own parameters.

(Seems to be a possible bug here when a connection no longer exists)

**MySQL Connector (with IP Address):**
 This connector allows you to add query parameters to the JDBC url. **Enable SSL** and append `useSSL=true` to the url. 
e.g.`jdbc:mysql://<ip>/<database>?useSSL=true`

This worked as expected and establishes new connections when required.
[Example Source Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgOuD.png)

Answer (score 1):

Suffering from this issue too, my experience is that using the [MySQL connector](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031) instead of the [Cloud SQL Connector](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020436) provides better stability in combination with setting [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) to a value above 12 hours.

---

This issue has been reported on the official Google Data Studio bug tracker. Please vote them up if you are also suffering from this !

- [130205306 MySQL connection does not exist](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130205306) Apr 9, 2019 04:36PM
- [118470083 Data source password not stored for MySQL sources.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118470083) Oct 26, 2018 01:24PM